# Run Import Product from CLI

Tags: magento2, import

it's possibile to run the Magento standard Import from CLI? I have to import product every night with that standard format.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Enterprise version, we can set up the Scheduled Import. This is an advanced feature of Magento EE: **System > Data Transfer > Scheduled Imports/Exports**. You can read more here: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/data-scheduled-import-export.html

If you're using the Community version, you should build your own module or reference to a free source [here](https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexport).